# Creating a class instance from a map of constructor parameter values

Tags: scala, reflection, dynamic, runtime

Say I have a following class:

```
case class Mock(id: Int, pty1: String, pty2: String)
```

How can I instantiate it from a following map dynamically?

```
val params = Map("id" → 234, "pty1" → "asdf", "pty2" → "asdf")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LOL ) Found out that I had a solution already implemented in my lib. Requires Scala 2.10.

```
  def instantiate[T <: AnyRef : Manifest](params: Map[String, Any]): T = {
    instantiate(Mirror.classToType(manifest[T].erasure), params).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
  def instantiate(tpe: Mirror.Type, params: Map[String, Any]) = {
    val p = constructorParams(tpe, params)
    require(
      params.size == p.size &&
      p.forall(p => params.contains(p.nameString)),
      "Params map `" + params + "` doesn't match `" + p + "`"
    )
    Option(Mirror.typeToJavaClass(tpe).getConstructor(p.map(p => Mirror.typeToJavaClass(p.tpe)): _*))
      .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("No appropriate constructor of `" + tpe + "` found"))
      .newInstance(p.map(p => params(p.nameString).asInstanceOf[Object]): _*)
  }
  private def constructorParams(tpe: Mirror.Type, params: Map[String, Any]) = {
    tpe.members.find(_.isConstructor).get.paramss(0)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can in a determistic way, since the names of the parameters are not part of the byte code and therefor at run time there is no way to know which String argument comes first and which second.